# A general way to add emphasis on words, actions, or people

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, phrase-request

I am looking for a way to emphasise words to put emphasis on words, actions, or people similar to the British English word *bloody:*

> This man is a bloody thief!
>
> Dieser Mann ist ein [?] Dieb!

Comment: *verdammt* (damned) may work

Comment: You might have chosen a better example. From your title I assume that you want something that you could also use to translate: “That’s a bloody good book.”

Answer (score 3):

You might form the compound with  *Scheiß-*, hence *Scheißdieb* (which, beware, means *shitty*). Or adjectivation, as alredy pointed out, with *verdammt*.

Comment: Same translation, without contraction: *beschissener Dieb* (shitty ≠ bloody).

Comment: @dakab habe ich gedacht, doch wusste ich nicht, ob es nicht härter, also schipfwilliger, als *bloody* klingt. Ist es nicht so?

Comment: Doch, finde ich auch. „Scheiß-“ kann noch halbwegs liebevoll für Alltagsgegenstände benutzt werden, aber „beschissen“ ist schon stärker. Je nach Kontext (wenn’s ernst gemeint ist) sind sie aber ungefähr austauschbar. Am besten passt wahrscheinlich „verdammt“ ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Riesen-** often works,  but not always. 
You can't say *Riesen-Dieb*, but **Riesen-Arschloch (=big ashole)**,  **Riesen-Depp (=big idiot)** or **Riesen-Sache (=big deal)** are common.

**Verdammter Dieb**, **verdammtes Arschloch** and **verdammter Depp** would work,  too. But it's uncommon to say eine *verdammte Sache*.  You would say instead **eine verdammt große Sache** or **eine verdammt komplizierte Sache**.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer depends a bit on the use case.

If you’re **learning German** and need a way to express intensity in a (mildly) foul way, I’d suggest to adopt the prefix *Scheiß-* lit. ‘shit, shitty’ – which may also mean ‘bad’ – for where you‘d say *bloody* in British or *fucking* in American English. (I don’t know what Canadians, Australians, Indians etc. would use.) Note that all lexemes are somewhat related to bodily functions. I believe there is no blood-based swearword in German, by the way, whereas *fucking* now has a more literal cognate, *verfickt*. If you’d like to repeat the root for rhetoric effect, as in *fucking motherfucker* or alliterative *fucking fuck-face*, you may combine *Scheiß-* (also stand-alone as *der Scheiß* or *die Scheiße*) with the adjective *beschissen*, e.g. *beschissener Scheißkerl* ‘shitty shithead’ or, mixing in another word for excrements, *beschissene Kackscheiße* ‘shitty shit shite’.

> *Dieser Mann ist ein **Scheiß**dieb.*
>   *Dieser Mann ist ein **Kack**dieb.*
>   *Dieser Mann ist ein **beschissener** Dieb.*

If you‘re **translating** a text from English to German, *verdammt* ‘condemned, doomed, cursed’ may be a better choice, not least because it’s an adjective with two syllables, too (unless inflected). 
Unlike the words discussed above, it has its roots in religion (not necessarily Christianity) and may be boosted by *gott-* (and more in dialects). There are some standing expression like *verdammt noch mal / verdammt noch eins, verdammter Mist, verdammte Axt*.

> *Dieser Mann ist ein **verdammter** Dieb.*
>   *Dieser Mann ist ein **gottverdammter** Dieb.*

There are more prefixes that may be used as intensifier, but are not as generally applicable, e.g. *Super-* or – to also get animal-based curses in here – *Sau-*, which incidentally both don’t work with the example, although I cannot tell exactly why (maybe because it could translate to ‘master thief’ and ‘pig thief’ respectively). The former, like similar *Ober-* (not *Über-*!), works best with insults, as in *Superarschloch*, the latter works well with adjectives, e.g. *saugut* ‘super good’.

> *Dieser Mann ist ein ***Super**dieb.*
>   *Dieser Mann ist ein ***Sau**dieb.*

In many cases, though, there are also more specialized, established expressions of adjective plus noun or just a compound noun.

> *Dieser Mann ist ein **elender** Dieb.* – ‘miserable’
>   *Dieser Mann ist ein **räudiger** Dieb.* – from *räudiger Hund/Köter/…* ‘mangy dog’
>   *Dieser Mann ist ein **gemeiner** Dieb.* – means both ‘common’ (oldish) and ‘mean’, may be prefixed by *hunds-* ‘doggish’
>   *Dieser Mann ist ein **übler** Dieb.* – ‘awful’, may become *übelst* as an adverb

Answer (score 0):

*dreckiger* would probably work fine, too.

Comment: Das ist richtig, aber nicht dreckig richtig.